# Unable to uninstall maas completely

Tags: maas

I'm not able to uninstall MAAS

```
sudo apt-get purge maas ; sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'maas' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up maas-region-controller (1.2+bzr1373+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Considering dependency proxy for proxy_http:
Module proxy already enabled
Module proxy_http already enabled
Module expires already enabled
Module wsgi already enabled
sed: -e expression #1, char 91: unterminated `s' command
dpkg: error processing maas-region-controller (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of maas-dns:
 maas-dns depends on maas-region-controller (= 1.2+bzr1373+dfsg-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package maas-region-controller is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing maas-dns (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 maas-region-controller
 maas-dns
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up maas-region-controller (1.2+bzr1373+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Considering dependency proxy for proxy_http:
Module proxy already enabled
Module proxy_http already enabled
Module expires already enabled
Module wsgi already enabled
sed: -e expression #1, char 91: unterminated `s' command
dpkg: error processing maas-region-controller (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of maas-dns:
 maas-dns depends on maas-region-controller (= 1.2+bzr1373+dfsg-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package maas-region-controller is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing maas-dns (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 maas-region-controller
 maas-dns
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

this stands out to me, in the walls of text:dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of maas-dns: maas-dns depends on maas-region-controller (= 1.2+bzr1373+dfsg-0ubuntu1); however: Package maas-region-controller is not configured yet.
try reinstalling and configuring the maas-region-controller

Answer (score -1):

This looks like you do not have the directory `/var/log/maas` 
just create this directory and re-try installation. it should work.